# Why is my Card Layout blank after adding a JTextField?

Tags: java, swing

I am adding player name input to my rock, paper, scissors game, and as far as I know, I can just use a different card with a JTextField, create a string, and then use that to replace "Player 1/Player 2." The only problem is, when I add my TextFields to a panel, that is then added to a cardLayout, which is finally added to the frame, everything is blank. Here is the example code.

```
final CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
final JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);

JPanel pname = new JPanel();

JTextField p1name = new JTextField(20);
JTextField p2name = new JTextField(20);

pname.add(p1name);
pname.add(p2name);

cardPanel.add(pname, "pname");

add(cardPanel);

cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "pname");
```

I have tried everything I have found online. I am running JRE 7, and the last time I checked, it ran fine on JRE 6 (that is likely to have changed by now since I have been messing with it.) Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Full code, poorly indented, (trying to work on my neatness)

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class RPS extends JFrame {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new RPS();
  }
  public RPS() {
super("Rock, Paper, Scissors");

setSize(300, 300);
setResizable(false);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setVisible(true);

//Adds all of the components.

final CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
final JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
JPanel pname = new JPanel();
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2r = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2p = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2s = new JPanel();
JPanel finish = new JPanel();

final JButton P1Rock = new JButton("Rock");
final JButton P1Paper = new JButton("Paper");
final JButton P1Scissors = new JButton("Scissors");

final JButton P2Rockr = new JButton("Rock");
final JButton P2Paperr = new JButton("Paper");
final JButton P2Scissorsr = new JButton("Scissors");

final JButton P2Rockp = new JButton("Rock");
final JButton P2Paperp = new JButton("Paper");
final JButton P2Scissorsp = new JButton("Scissors");

final JButton P2Rocks = new JButton("Rock");
final JButton P2Papers = new JButton("Paper");
final JButton P2Scissorss = new JButton("Scissors");

final JButton playAgain = new JButton("Play again?");

final JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel(" ");

JTextField p1name = new JTextField(20);
JTextField p2name = new JTextField(20);

JLabel P1turn = new JLabel("It is Player 1's turn. Choose:");
JLabel P2turnr = new JLabel("It is Player 2's turn. Choose:");
JLabel P2turnp = new JLabel("It is Player 2's turn. Choose:");
JLabel P2turns = new JLabel("It is Player 2's turn. Choose:");

//Sets up and adds all of the panels.

pname.add(p1name);
pname.add(p2name);

panel1.add(P1turn);
panel1.add(P1Rock);
panel1.add(P1Paper);
panel1.add(P1Scissors);
panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));

panel2r.add(P2turnr);
panel2r.add(P2Rockr);
panel2r.add(P2Paperr);
panel2r.add(P2Scissorsr);
panel2r.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));

panel2p.add(P2turnp);
panel2p.add(P2Rockp);
panel2p.add(P2Paperp);
panel2p.add(P2Scissorsp);
panel2p.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));

panel2s.add(P2turns);
panel2s.add(P2Rocks);
panel2s.add(P2Papers);
panel2s.add(P2Scissorss);
panel2s.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));

finish.add(statusLabel);
finish.add(playAgain);
finish.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

cardPanel.add(pname, "pname");
cardPanel.add(panel1, "player1");
cardPanel.add(panel2r, "player2r");
cardPanel.add(panel2p, "player2p");
cardPanel.add(panel2s, "player2s");
cardPanel.add(finish, "finish");

add(cardPanel);

cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "pname");

//Determines player 1's choice.

P1Rock.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "player2r");
  }
});

P1Paper.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "player2p");
  }
});

P1Scissors.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "player2s");
  }
});

playAgain.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "player1");
  }
});

//Determines player 2's choice and prints a result.

P2Rockr.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    statusLabel.setText("It's a tie!");
    cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "finish");
  }
});

P2Paperr.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    statusLabel.setText("Player 2 wins! Paper covers Rock.");
    cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "finish");
  }
});

P2Scissorsr.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    statusLabel.setText("Player 1 wins! Rock crushes Scissors.");
    cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "finish");
  }
});

P2Rockp.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    statusLabel.setText("Player 1 wins! Paper covers Rock!");
    cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "finish");
  }
});

P2Paperp.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    statusLabel.setText("It's a tie!");
    cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "finish");
  }
});

P2Scissorsp.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    statusLabel.setText("Player 2 wins! Scissors cut paper.");
    cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "finish");
  }
});

P2Rocks.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    statusLabel.setText("Player 2 wins! Rock crushes Scissors.");
    cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "finish");
  }
});

P2Papers.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    statusLabel.setText("Player 1 wins! Scissors cut Paper.");
    cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "finish");
  }
});

P2Scissorss.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    statusLabel.setText("It's a tie!");
    cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "finish");
  }
});

  }
}
```

EDIT:
Just tested it again on my JRE 6 laptop, no problems. I'm starting to think that the problem is with my desktop. My compiler is Dr. Java.

Comment: Why do you have 12 different buttons?

Comment: @peeskillet The buttons are to essentially have a map with the card layout that both allowed for a replay button and JButtons instead of JRadioButtons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at how you're creating your `CardLayout`

```
    cardPanel.add(pname, "pname");
    cardPanel.add(panel1, "player1");
    cardPanel.add(panel2r, "player2r");
    cardPanel.add(panel2p, "player2p");
    cardPanel.add(panel2s, "player2s");
    cardPanel.add(finish, "finish");
```

- First you're adding `pname` which consists of only two text fields

See here

```
JPanel pname = new JPanel();
JTextField p1name = new JTextField(20);
JTextField p2name = new JTextField(20);
pname.add(p1name);
pname.add(p2name);
```

Since you first show `pname`, `cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "pname");` all you will see are the text fields. And that panel has no button or listener that would advance the card layout to a different panel

I don't really want to get into all the grouping of every single component. But think about what you want on each panel and add those components to a different panel, then add then each to to the group layout. Remember there needs to be a button in each view that will be able to show a different view.

I'd recommend even grouping all you components from one panel together in your code, to make it more readable as to which component goes into which label. The reason I don't want to go into detail about the groupings is because your code is hard to read 1) because components are all over the place and 2) component names are very similar.

**Edit:** Take a look at this example. You can run it. It might not give you the exact functionality you're looking for, but you can compare it to your.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PeeskilletsRPS extends JPanel{

    // buttons
    JButton P1Rock = new JButton("Rock");
    JButton P1Paper = new JButton("Paper");
    JButton P1Scissors = new JButton("Scissors");
    JButton P2Rock = new JButton("Rock");
    JButton P2Paper = new JButton("Paper");
    JButton P2Scissors = new JButton("Scissors");
    JButton jbtPlay = new JButton("Play");

    // panels
    JPanel namesPanel;
    JPanel player1Panel;
    JPanel player2Panel;

    // finish panel
    JPanel finishPanel;
    JButton playAgain;
    JLabel result;

    // CardLayout and main Panel
    CardLayout cardLayout;
    JPanel cardPanel;

    String player1Choice;
    String player2Choice;
    String status;

    String player2Name;
    String player1Name;


    public PeeskilletsRPS(){
        // names panel
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,1));
        p1.add(new JLabel("Player 1 Name: "));
        final JTextField jtfname1 = new JTextField(15);
        p1.add(jtfname1);
        p1.add(new JLabel("Player 2 Name: "));
        final JTextField jtfname2 = new JTextField(15);
        p1.add(jtfname2);
        namesPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        namesPanel.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        namesPanel.add(jbtPlay, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        // player 1 panel
        JPanel player1Buttons = new JPanel();
        player1Buttons.add(P1Rock);
        player1Buttons.add(P1Paper);
        player1Buttons.add(P1Scissors);
        player1Panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        player1Panel.add(player1Buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        final JLabel jlblPlayer1 = new JLabel("  ");
        jlblPlayer1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        player1Panel.add(jlblPlayer1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // player 2 panel
        JPanel player2Buttons = new JPanel();
        player2Buttons.add(P2Rock);
        player2Buttons.add(P2Paper);
        player2Buttons.add(P2Scissors);
        player2Panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        player2Panel.add(player2Buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        final JLabel jlblPlayer2 = new JLabel("  ");
        jlblPlayer2.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        player2Panel.add(jlblPlayer2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        // finish panel
        result = new JLabel("  ");
        playAgain = new JButton("Play Agian");
        finishPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        finishPanel.add(playAgain, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        finishPanel.add(result, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        result.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        // create card layout
        cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        cardPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);
        cardPanel.add(namesPanel, "names");
        cardPanel.add(player1Panel, "player1");
        cardPanel.add(player2Panel, "player2");
        cardPanel.add(finishPanel, "finish");

        // add cardPanel to main panel
        add(cardPanel);

        P1Rock.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                player1Choice = "Rock";
                cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "player2");
            }
        });
        P1Paper.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                player1Choice = "Paper";
                cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "player2");
            }
        });
        P1Scissors.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                player1Choice = "Scissors";
                cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "player2");
            }
        });

        P2Rock.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                player2Choice = "Rock";
                checkWinner();
                result.setText(status);
                cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "finish");
            }
        });

        P2Paper.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                player2Choice = "Paper";
                checkWinner();
                result.setText(status);
                cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "finish");
            }
        });

        P2Scissors.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                player2Choice = "Scissors";
                checkWinner();
                result.setText(status);
                cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "finish");
            }
        });

        jbtPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                player1Name = jtfname1.getText();
                player2Name = jtfname2.getText();
                jlblPlayer1.setText(player1Name + " choose: ");
                jlblPlayer2.setText(player2Name + " choose: ");
                cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "player1");

            }
        });

        playAgain.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "player1");
            }
        });
    }

    private void checkWinner(){
        if (player1Choice.equals(player2Choice)) 
            status = "It's a Tie!";
        else if ("Rock".equals(player1Choice) && "Paper".equals(player2Choice))
            status = player2Name + " wins. Paper beats Rock!";
        else if ("Rock".equals(player1Choice) && "Scissors".equals(player2Choice))
            status = player1Name + " wins. Rock beats Scissors!";
        else if ("Paper".equals(player1Choice) && "Rock".equals(player2Choice))
            status = player1Name + " wins. Paper beats Rock!";
        else if ("Paper".equals(player1Choice) && "Scissors".equals(player2Choice))
            status = player2Name + " wins. Scissors beats Paper!";
        else if ("Scissors".equals(player1Choice) && "Paper".equals(player2Choice))
            status = player1Name + " wins. Scissors beats Paper!";
        else if ("Scissors".equals(player1Choice) && "Rock".equals(player2Choice))
            status = player2Name + " wins. Rock beats Scissors!";   
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Peeskillet's Rock, Paper, Scissors");
                frame.add(new PeeskilletsRPS());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I will try this. I have been trying to make my code cleaner, it just gets messy. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at my Edit. Maybe you'll get some ideas from it.

Answer (score 3):

Works fine for me, but maybe something you are doing that you're not showing us...

[image: Cards]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestCardLayout100 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestCardLayout100();
    }

    public TestCardLayout100() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            final CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
            final JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);

            JPanel pname = new JPanel();

            JTextField p1name = new JTextField(20);
            JTextField p2name = new JTextField(20);

            pname.add(p1name);
            pname.add(p2name);

            cardPanel.add(pname, "pname");

            add(cardPanel);

            cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "pname");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call pack() and then revalidate(). In your case:

```
cardPanel.add(pname, "pname");
cardPanel.add(panel1, "player1");
cardPanel.add(panel2r, "player2r");
cardPanel.add(panel2p, "player2p");
cardPanel.add(panel2s, "player2s");
cardPanel.add(finish, "finish");

add(cardPanel);

cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "pname");
pack();
revalidate();
```